# VHDL - Can't stop my countdown timer at 00:00:00

Tags: vhdl

I wrote this code, connected a 100Hz clock and the exits are Bin 7 Segments Decoders. The exits in this code are the time.
The time starts at 10:00:00 because it is a basketball game.
My problem is that the time should stop at 00:00:00, but continues to F9:59:99. 
What should I do to make it stop automatically?

```
              entity Timer is
                port(clock      :   in std_logic;
                        enable  :   in std_logic;
                      reset     :   in std_logic;
                        UniCent :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                     DezCent    :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                  UniSeg        :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                  DezSeg        :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                  UniMin        :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                   DezMin       :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));

                end Timer;

                       architecture Behavioral of Timer is
                       signal s_UnidadesCent : unsigned(3 downto 0):="0000";                                                                                  
                     signal s_DezenasCent  : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
                     signal s_UnidadesSeg  : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
                     signal s_DezenasSeg   : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
                     signal s_UnidadesMin  : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
                     signal s_DezenasMin   : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0001";

                       begin
                            process(clock)
                            begin 
                               if (rising_edge(clock)) then
                                   if (reset = '1') then
                                        s_UnidadesCent <= "0000";
                                        s_DezenasCent <= "0000";
                                       s_UnidadesSeg <= "0000";
                                        s_DezenasSeg <= "0000";
                                       s_UnidadesMin <= "0000";
                                       s_DezenasMin <= "0001";

                        elsif (enable = '1') then

                        if (s_UnidadesCent = "0000" and s_DezenasCent = "0000" and s_UnidadesSeg = "0000" and s_DezenasSeg = "0000" and s_UnidadesMin = "0000" and s_DezenasMin = "0000") then

                                    s_UnidadesCent <= "0000";
                                    s_DezenasCent <= "0000";
                                    s_UnidadesSeg <= "0000";
                                    s_DezenasSeg <= "0000";
                                    s_UnidadesMin <= "0000";
                                    s_DezenasMin <= "0000"; 

                    else    
                        s_UnidadesCent <= s_UnidadesCent - 1;



                            if (s_UnidadesCent = "0000" and s_DezenasCent /= "0000") then 
                                s_UnidadesCent  <= "1001";
                                s_DezenasCent <= s_DezenasCent - 1; 

                                    if (s_UnidadesSeg = "0000" and s_DezenasSeg /= "0000") then
                                            s_UnidadesSeg <= s_unidadesSeg;
                                            s_DezenasSeg <= s_DezenasSeg;

                                            if (s_UnidadesMin = "0000") then
                                                    s_DezenasMin <= s_DezenasMin;
                                                    s_UnidadesMin <= s_unidadesMin;
                                            end if;

                                    elsif (s_UnidadesSeg = "0000" and s_DezenasSeg = "0000") then
                                            s_UnidadesSeg <= "1001";
                                            s_DezenasSeg <= "0101";
                                            s_UnidadesMin <= s_UnidadesMin - 1;

                                            if (s_UnidadesMin = "0000") then
                                                    s_DezenasMin <= s_DezenasMin - 1;
                                                    s_UnidadesMin <= "1001";
                                            end if;

                                    end if;


                            elsif (s_UnidadesCent = "0000" and s_DezenasCent = "0000") then
                                s_UnidadesSeg <= s_UnidadesSeg - 1;
                                s_UnidadesCent  <= "1001";
                                s_DezenasCent <= "1001";

                                    if (s_UnidadesCent = "0000" and s_DezenasCent = "0000" and s_UnidadesSeg = "0000" and s_DezenasSeg /= "0000") then
                                            s_UnidadesSeg <= "1001";
                                            s_DezenasSeg <= s_DezenasSeg - 1;



                                    elsif (s_UnidadesSeg = "0000" and s_DezenasSeg = "0000" and s_UnidadesCent = "0000" and s_DezenasCent = "0000") then
                                            s_UnidadesSeg <= "1001";
                                            s_DezenasSeg <= "0101";
                                            s_UnidadesMin <= s_UnidadesMin - 1;

                                            if (s_UnidadesMin = "0000") then
                                                    s_DezenasMin <= s_DezenasMin - 1;
                                                    s_UnidadesMin <= "1001";
                                            end if;

                                    end if;


                            end if; 
                    end if;


            else 
                s_UnidadesCent <= s_UnidadesCent;
                s_DezenasCent <= s_DezenasCent;
                s_UnidadesSeg <= s_UnidadesSeg;
                s_DezenasSeg <= s_DezenasSeg;
                s_UnidadesMin <= s_UnidadesMin;
                s_DezenasMin <= s_DezenasMin;

            end if; 

        end if;
end process;


UniCent <= std_logic_vector(s_UnidadesCent);
DezCent <= std_logic_vector(s_DezenasCent);
UniSeg <= std_logic_vector(s_UnidadesSeg);
DezSeg <= std_logic_vector(s_DezenasSeg);
UniMin <= std_logic_vector(s_UnidadesMin);
DezMin <= std_logic_vector(s_DezenasMin);
```

end Behavioral;

Comment: It probably is somewhere in your if elsif structure but I can't see it because the indents are all over the place. Please cleanup you code Also please provide your test-bench so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Your last if statement needs to prevent decrementing s_DezenasMin and setting s_UnidadesMin to 9 when s_DezenasMin is 0.  ('dozens' for 'tens'? Galego/Portugese?) - `if s_UnidadesMin = "0000" and s_DezenasMin /= "0000" then  s_DezenasMin <= s_DezenasMin - 1;  s_UnidadesMin <= "1001" end if;` Without a [mcve] the result can't be veified.

Comment: I cleaned my code and now it works. It was some problem with s_DezenasCent.
I forgot to thank to Oldfart and user1155120. Thanks for trying to help.
By the way, yes the language is Portuguese.